# Advection Term in the Lorenz 96 Model

Tags: fluid-dynamics, atmospheric-science, non-linear-systems, chaos-theory, complex-systems

The [Lorenz 96](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_96_model) Model is defined as
$$\frac{dx_i}{dt}=\underbrace{(x_{i+1}-x_{i-2})x_{i-1}}_{advection}-x_i+F$$
with some forcing $F$ and periodic boundary conditions so that $x_{i+N}=x_i$ for some $N$.

I do not have an intuitive explanation why the first term on the RHS of the equation describes some advection process. The advection term can be multiplied out to yield $x_{i+1} x_{i-1}$ and $-x_{i-1} x_{i-2}$. The first term means an increase in $x_i$ in time when $x_{i+1}$ and $x_{i-1}$ have the same sign and the second term means an increase in $x_i$ when $x_{i-1}$ and $x_{i-2}$ have different signs.

I don't understand how this relates to the concept of advection.

Comment: I understand that the advection term conserves energy, defined as $\sum_i x_i^2$, and that seems plausible for an advection term (see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.07767)) but I do not see the advection process "intuitively" from the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fluid equation's [convective term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations#Incompressible_flow), $(\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla)\mathbf{u}$, becomes in 1-D:

$$ u\;\partial u/ \partial x,$$

which can be discretized in a variety of ways (see, e.g., [1](https://www.uni-muenster.de/imperia/md/content/physik_tp/lectures/ws2016-2017/num_methods_i/advection.pdf), [2](https://peymandavvalo.github.io/linear_1d_advection_equation.html), [3](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/329/lectures/node90.html) and [4](https://doi.org/10.1155/MPE.2005.61)) involving quadratic terms and different lattice sites, such as

$$ u_{i}(u_{i+1}-u_{i-1}) \quad \text{ or} \label{dis}\tag{1} $$
$$ u_{i}(u_{i+1}-u_{i}) \text{ for }u_{i}<0,\quad  u_{i}(u_{i}-u_{i-1}) \text{ for } u_{i}>0, $$

among others.

As a toy model, Lorenz 96 offers only a rough approximation of the physics, so if the term is advection-like and preserves energy — and the discretizations above are similar enough (using $u$ for $x$) to L96's $u_{i-1}(u_{i+1}-u_{i-2})$ — that's enough to call it "advection".

As for the intuition, the main differences with respect to the main discretization (\ref{dis}) are i) a shift in the position index, $i \to i-1$, which I guess accounts for a preferential direction of wave propagation in the model, and ii) a one-sided next nearest neighbor interaction (the $u_{i-2}$ dependence) whose role, apart from appearing to make it less local, isn't that clear to me.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I thought I would maybe miss something obvious about why this term is called an advection term in so many sources. With the one-sided next next nearest neighbor interaction you mean the $-u_{i-1}u_{i-2}$ term and not $u_{i-1}u_{i+1}$, right?

Comment: @Holgerillo You're welcome. To me it was not really obvious either (apart from coupling flows from different sites). I still think the sites $i-1$ and $i-2$ are nearest neighbors and $i-1$ and $i+1$ next nearest neighbors. (BTW, the "next next" was a mistake, as they are just two links apart, not three.)

Comment: Ok, but we calculate the dynamics for $u_i$ so why would you consider $u_{i-2}$ a nearest neighbour in the Lorenz 96 Model?

Comment: @Holgerillo You're right. In part I was looking at the EDO's rhs as if it were defining the dynamics like, say, a Hamiltonian, which it isn't. I've already amended the answer.